# Exception ETIMEDOUT in node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

I write application for iOS, which uses Socket.IO. Sometimes my server JS-script falls with this error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

What I know is:

- Script workes fine when I use only application for Android. That app uses Socket.IO for Android
- Script workes fine when I use only web-client (yeap, with socket.IO)
- Script startes to fall when I use iOS app.
- Crash happens not always and not right away. Script falls after 5-10 minutes after connection and may crash, but may not.

So, I think the problem is in server library for socket.io, but exception fires only when iOS-client connecting.

How can I handle this exception?

**UPDATE**

There is problem was in the OAuth module on my node.js-server, which tried to check app token but had timeout to vk.com
I've edited vkapi module in my node.js server by adding "on" event for "https.get" function:
Was:

```
https.get(options, function(res) {

            var apiResponse = new String();
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                apiResponse += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end',  function() {
                var o = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
                if (o.error) { self.emit('appServerTokenNotReady', o);

                } else { 
                    self.token = o.access_token;
                    self.emit('appServerTokenReady');
                }
            });
        });
```

Now:

```
https.get(options, function(res) {

            var apiResponse = new String();
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                apiResponse += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end',  function() {
                var o = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
                if (o.error) { self.emit('appServerTokenNotReady', o);

                } else { 
                    self.token = o.access_token;
                    self.emit('appServerTokenReady');
                }
            });
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('HTTPS error');
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to handle error at events.js:85 ?

Comment: @Dyrk, how I can do it? I can't even find events.js. Seems it node.js system script

Comment: If your server-side script is emitting that error, then you must be performing some kind of client connection on the server-side (e.g. an HTTP request or plain TCP client connection). This error occurs when you try to connect to another server and that server doesn't respond within a timely manner.

Comment: @user2627744 yes, it is. So how do you want to fix a server's code without access to it? You have some unhandled error in Node, so first of all it's better to see what is happening in events.js file.

Comment: @mscdex, seems to be true. I use OAuth tokens check at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can handle these kinds of async errors by listening for the `error` event on whatever (e.g. request, connection, etc.) object.

The `error` event is special in that if there are currently no event handlers for it when it is emitted, the error will be thrown instead.

Comment: Why does it do that without providing more context? If you are on an iOS app, and the error is returned to iOS, the app could display the server error in a context that looks like it was a client error (i.e. the client connection to node.js suffered at timeout.)?